# Problema con Botón Flotante (No se cierra)

Tags: java, android, xml, botón

El problema es que cuando pulso en el botón flotante me hace la acción, pero cuando vuelvo a la Activity principal, sigue el menú flotante abierto, por qué no se cierra? Dejo un GIF para que veáis mejor el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

MainActivity.java

```
import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton;
import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    FloatingActionMenu btn_flo_menu;
    FloatingActionButton btn_flo_1, btn_flo_2, btn_flo_3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_flo_menu = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.icon_btn_flo_menu);
        btn_flo_1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_btn_flo_1);
        btn_flo_2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_btn_flo_2);
        btn_flo_3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_btn_flo_3);


        btn_flo_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editarPersona(0);
            }
        });


        btn_flo_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
        btn_flo_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/base_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/icon_btn_flo_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#3F51B5"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#3F51B5"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/icon_btn_flo_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_btn_flo_1"
        fab:fab_label="@string/btn_flo_1"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/icon_btn_flo_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon2"
        fab:fab_label="Vacío"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/icon_btn_flo_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon3"
        fab:fab_label="Vacío"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega esta linea en la clase y listo.

```
btn_flo_menu = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.icon_btn_flo_menu);
//Agrega esto.
btn_flo_menu.close(false);
// false hace referencia a si cerrarlo con la animacion o no en este caso no.

//O en el listener del que presionas.
btn_flo_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editarPersona(0);
        btn_flo_menu.close(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: prueba con solo `btn_flo_menu.close(false);`

Comment: ahora sí! Muchas gracias, edita tu respuesta y la marco como solucionada, gracias de nuevo !

Answer (score 2):

En realidad no es el botón el que se debe cerrar, es el `FloatingActionMenu`, considero es mejor validar si esta abierto para cerrarlo mediante el método `close()`

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
      if (floatingactionmenu.isOpened()) { //esta abierto?
         floatingactionmenu.close(true); //Cierra menú
      }
 }
```

El código sería:

```
btn_flo_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editarPersona(0);
        if (btn_flo_menu.isOpened()) { //esta abierto?
            btn_flo_menu.close(true); //Cierra menú
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: En el caso de este componente ya solo hace la verificación.

Comment: A que te refieres? cual componente?

Comment: El FloatingActionMenu ya lo hace solo en su código interno

Comment: ya revisaste el código del método close() del menú ?

Comment: Si, y lo tiene agregado.

Comment: ah ver revisaré ahora..